# Инъекция завистимостей не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Здравствуйте попытаюсь объяснить как я вижу исполнение кода, вытекает следующая проблема:
есть роутер

```
@test_router.get('/testing')
async def test(service: Annotated[BasketService, Depends()], user = Depends(get_active_user)):
    print([service.user, user])
    return {}
```

сначала Depends вызовет BasketService и создаст его экземпляр, BasketService наследуется от базового сервиса:

```
class BaseService:
    def __init__(self, uow: IUnitOfWork = Depends(db_provider),
                 user: User = Depends(get_active_user)):
        self.uow: IUnitOfWork = uow
        self.user = user

class BasketService(BaseService):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

get_active_user и db_provider это заглушки

```
async def get_active_user() -> User:
    raise NotImplementedError

async def db_provider() -> UnitOfWork:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

во время старта приложения вызывается setup:

```
def setup(app: FastAPI, session_factory: async_sessionmaker):
    provider = DbProvider(session_factory)
    app.dependency_overrides[get_active_user] = current_user
    app.dependency_overrides[db_provider] = provider.get_uow
```

который в свою очередь переопределяет зависимость
первая зависимость реализована так :

```
async def current_user():
    return "какой-то результат"
```

вторая так:

```
class DbProvider:
    def __init__(self, session_factory):
        self.session_factory = session_factory

    def get_uow(self):
        return UnitOfWork(session_factory=self.session_factory)
```

ну и сам результат роутера

```
[Depends(get_active_user), 'какой-то результат']
```

я не понимаю почему в этом случае не отрабатывает `Depends(get_active_user)` но отрабатывает `uow: IUnitOfWork = Depends(db_provider)`, объясните пожалуйста